# Centered flex box with display=none element causing unreadable overflow off screen

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three columns within the flex box container, two visible and one hidden. The first two have very little content; the third one has several pages of content. I want all three to be initially vertically centered, but since the third one will overflow off the page, I want it (when made visible) to end up filling to the top of the page and then scrolling down. How can I have centred items in the flex box that overflow naturally in this way?

What's happening now in my code below is that when the third column is made visible, it overflows off the top and bottom of the page, without scroll, so that its impossible to read the first part of the content.

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="column column-left">
            column one
    </div>
    <div class="column column-right">
        column two      
    </div>
    <div class="column-hidden column" data-id="1">
      column three
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
}

html, body{
height: 100%;
}

.flex-container{
height: 100%;
display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
-webkit-align-items: center;
   align-items: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
} 

.column{
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
}


.column-left{
    display: visible;
}
.column-right{
    display: visible;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
}

.column-hidden{
   display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
//clicking on button does the following to show hidden column 
$('.column-left').removeClass('column-left').addClass('column-hidden');
$('.column-right').removeClass('column-right').addClass('column-left');
$(".column[data-id='" + id + "']").addClass('column-right').removeClass('column-hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

Played a bit with your code. I rearranged `align-items` from `.flex-container` to `.column`, which is also `display: flex;`. For scrolling I think you should have additional absolutely positioned container for the content.. I used `P`.

Sample here http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/gpqLLZ

p.s. Some hints about your code. `flex-direction`'s initial value is `row`, so you don't have to write it. And `visible` is not a property of `display` ;)

Comment: There's is also an another way too.. slightly different, but take a look:
http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/ZGwBvL

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! I was a little unclear: I don't want the column itself to be a scrollable div (overflow: scroll) but just to be properly visible when the user scrolls down the page (overflow: auto probably--it's just positioned wrong).